# Detect stationary device using GPS

Tags: android, gps

I am creating an app that alerts user if he has been stationary for a few minutes(say 10).

I find it easy to detect motion, using LocationListener which triggers a function if device moved a certain distance.

However, I want something different. I want a function to be called if the device did not move  for a certain duration of time.

How I achieve this?

Comment: How stationary do they need to be? You could use the accelerometer to be more precise.

Comment: It is pretty coarse. Say, less than 100 meters is considered stationary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily set a timer and when the LocationListener fires, reset the timer to zero. If the timer reaches 10 minutes, then you know that the user hasn't moved. The downside to this approach is that the timer must continue to run, so you will need to install as a service.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: But LocationListener fires when there has been some movement. So in this case, it will never fire.

Comment: Exactly. You only _reset_ the timer when it fires and, thus, when it doesn't fire, your timer will reach 10 minutes and you know that they haven't moved.

Answer (score 1):

something like this might do the trick I am not sure if this code works, I haven't test it, but generally what you need to do is get the current location. then user a timer to check it in 10 minutes if it is still in the same location. if not  use an intent to start a new activity.

```
private double locationcheck;

locationcheck = this.getcurrentlocation();

public double[] getcurrentlocation(){
double[] locations= new String[2];
l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
locations[0] = l.getLatitude();
locations[0] = l.getLongitude();
return 
}
```

then use this method to check it :

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
           Timer t = new Timer(); 
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                    public void run() { 
                            handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                                    public void run() { 

                                        if (locationcheck!=this.getcurrentlocation()) {

    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, YourActivity.class);
        StartActivity(i);

                                        }   
                                    } 
                            }); 
                    } 
            }, 3000,10000);
```

Comment: However remember the timer will keep going and will use so much of the memory, so it is better to use it in service and call the service from the MapActivity