# ways of using latitude and longitude to get top 5 locations

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I have an android application which gave me, data of latitude and longitude of my past 3 days whereabouts. I need to know my top 5 location where i spent most time. I have every 5 minute latitude and longitude. As we know if the phone is i stationary it will fluctuate a little so no 2 latitudes and longitudes are same. I search, and get to know that we can use clustering for this. But i would like to know is there any other way?
During night, the phone was stationary still the values of latitude and longitude keeps fluctuating and no 2 values are same.

Comment: are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212321/detect-stationary-device-using-gps

Comment: no. I have the data. I need to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Locations  data use Geofencing to calculate time spent at specific location
 Refer:
1.http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

2.[Tracking more than 100 simultaneous geofences with the new Android API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353150/tracking-more-than-100-simultaneous-geofences-with-the-new-android-api)